# Cache and Sync data on iOS devices

Tags: ios, caching, core-data, offline-caching

We have a requirement to be able to store the data on device and make it available even when device is off network, and when device comes back to network it should be able to sync the stored data and be able to update the stored data with latest server data and so on. I understand that lots of this needs to be implemented using sync/notification/versioning stuff ourself.

However are there any recommended framework/API (other than vanilla Core Data) that people use to store large amount of data to be stored/cached on iOS devices? Any reliable and intelligent caching solution out there?

Any recommendation of this sort will be very helpful.

Comment: When offline, is it read only?